# Error in Javascript: Unexpected token (

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, syntax-error

My page is throwing a javascript error, but I can't figure out why. I'm trying to debug a script that was imported to my client's site. It's throwing the error here:

```
function(t){
    e._trigger("receive",t,this._uiHash(this))
}
```

The error is "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ("

For context, here is the chunk of code it is located in. Unfortunately I don't really know what purpose these functions serve, but the error is preventing the page from loading correctly. Hopefully this Javascript is enough to give the context, the full script is very long.

```
_clear: function(e, t) {
    this.reverting = !1;
    var i, n = [];
    if (!this._noFinalSort && this.currentItem.parent().length && this.placeholder
        .before(this.currentItem), this._noFinalSort = null, this.helper[0] ===
        this.currentItem[0]) {
        for (i in this._storedCSS)
            ("auto" === this._storedCSS[i] || "static" === this._storedCSS[
                i]) && (this._storedCSS[i] = "");
        this.currentItem.css(this._storedCSS).removeClass(
            "ui-sortable-helper")
    } else this.currentItem.show();
    for (this.fromOutside && !t && n.push(function(e) {
            this._trigger("receive", e, this._uiHash(this.fromOutside))
        }), !this.fromOutside && this.domPosition.prev === this.currentItem
        .prev().not(".ui-sortable-helper")[0] && this.domPosition.parent ===
        this.currentItem.parent()[0] || t || n.push(function(e) {
            this._trigger("update", e, this._uiHash())
        }), this !== this.currentContainer && (t || (n.push(function(e) {
            this._trigger("remove", e, this._uiHash())
        }), n.push(function(e) {
            return

            function(t) {
                e._trigger("receive", t, this._uiHash(this))
            }
        }.call(this, this.currentContainer)), n.push(function(e) {
            return

            function(t) {
                e._trigger("update", t, this._uiHash(this))
            }
        }.call(this, this.currentContainer)))), i = this.containers.length -
        1; i >= 0; i--) t || n.push(function(e) {
            return function(t) {
                e._trigger("deactivate", t, this._uiHash(this))
            }
        }.call(this, this.containers[i])), this.containers[i].containerCache
        .over && (n.push(function(e) {
                return

                function(t) {
                    e._trigger("out", t, this._uiHash(this))
                }
            }.call(this, this.containers[i])), this.containers[i].containerCache
            .over = 0);
    if (this.storedCursor && (this.document.find("body").css("cursor", this
            .storedCursor), this.storedStylesheet.remove()), this._storedOpacity &&
        this.helper.css("opacity", this._storedOpacity), this._storedZIndex &&
        this.helper.css("zIndex", "auto" === this._storedZIndex ? "" : this
            ._storedZIndex), this.dragging = !1, this.cancelHelperRemoval) {
        if (!t) {
            for (this._trigger("beforeStop", e, this._uiHash()), i = 0; n.length >
                i; i++) n[i].call(this, e);
            this._trigger("stop", e, this._uiHash())
        }
        return this.fromOutside = !1, !1
    }
    if (t || this._trigger("beforeStop", e, this._uiHash()), this.placeholder[
            0].parentNode.removeChild(this.placeholder[0]), this.helper[0] !==
        this.currentItem[0] && this.helper.remove(), this.helper = null, !t
    ) {
        for (i = 0; n.length > i; i++) n[i].call(this, e);
        this._trigger("stop", e, this._uiHash())
    }
    return this.fromOutside = !1, !0
}
```

If you want to look at the page, it's located [here](http://wma2.stage.pgdonors.org/)

Comment: just a suggestion- you can put your script on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) and click on JSHint, it highlights all the syntax errors

Comment: Or you could just put your code in [JSHint](http://jshint.com).

Answer (score 5):

Every section of your code that looks like:

```
            return

            function(t) {
                e._trigger("out", t, this._uiHash(this))
            }
```

is broken.  The rules of JavaScript automatic semicolon insertion are such that those `return` statements are treated as complete when the parser hits the newline. It has to look like:

```
            return function(t) {
                e._trigger("out", t, this._uiHash(this))
            }
```

That may seem astonishing, but it's true. The error you're getting happens because the parser thinks that that `function` keyword is opening a new function declaration statement, and in such a statement the function name is not optional.